# Ansible package_facts: set facts by comparing with another simple list

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm currently working on generating report for each inventory host thanks to ansible-cmdb. This tool is great but I have a problem to modify some facts:

I use the [package_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_facts_module.html) **module to register installed packages**. They are automatically registered in hostvars as a list of dicts like this (*ansible_facts.packages*):

```
"packages": {
    "accountsservice": [
        {
            "arch": "amd64",
            "name": "accountsservice",
            "source": "apt",
            "version": "0.6.40-2ubuntu11.3"
        }
    ],
    "acl": [
        {
            "arch": "amd64",
            "name": "acl",
            "source": "apt",
            "version": "2.2.52-3"
        }
    ],
    "acpid": [
        {
            "arch": "amd64",
            "name": "acpid",
            "source": "apt",
            "version": "1:2.0.26-1ubuntu2"
        }
    ]}
```

On the other side, I have a remote bash **script which outputs a simple list of package name manually installed on the host.** For each host, I want to compare the two list, if a package name is also in *ansible_facts.packages*, then add a key in packages fact for the desired package *"manual": true*. Otherwise, and if possible, add *"manual": false*. So, after comparison, facts should be set like this:

```
"packages": {
    "accountsservice": [
        {
            "arch": "amd64",
            "name": "accountsservice",
            "source": "apt",
            "version": "0.6.40-2ubuntu11.3",
            "manual": true
        }
    ],
    "acl": [
        {
            "arch": "amd64",
            "name": "acl",
            "source": "apt",
            "version": "2.2.52-3",
            "manual": false
        }
    ],
...}
```

Do you think it is possible in a proper way? I'm a newbie concerning handling JSON datastructures with Ansible, that is why I will do a workaround with a Python script since I'm working since some days on a proper way (with no success).

It would be a big help/step if I know how to do it properly.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Jinja is quite a powerful templating language, and you can declare new facts using the `set_facts` module, leading to something kind of like this:

```
  vars:
    the_list: |
      [
       {"name": "alpha"},
       {"name": "beta"}
      ]
    the_names: |
      ["alpha", "charlie"]
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
     new_list: |
      [
      {% set names_list = (the_names|from_json) %}
      {% for item in (the_list|from_json) %}
      {{ '' if loop.first else ',' }}
      {% set _ = item.update({"manual": item.name in names_list}) %}
      {{ item | to_json }}
      {% endfor %}
      ]
  - debug: var=item.manual verbosity=0
    with_items: '{{ new_list }}'
```

Where the `set _ =` part is because jinja only has the `set` statement to cause side-effects, and the rest is just coercion from text to an actual `dict`, and then the `with_items` coerces the text back into a rich object in the same way that the `--extra-vars` and friends do so for you: if it *looks* json-y, they treat it as such. We have to do `from_json` manually because that coercion is an *ansible* behavior, not a *jinja* behavior.

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer Matthew, I finally just wrote a custom Python module to add info to package_facts. I think I will push some feature requests for package_facts module (add a little summary for each package, e.g) !